# Unable to reset R rownames, rownames(df) returns NULL

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using the ukcars data set in the expsmooth package. I am trying to execute the following code:

```
decomp <- stl(ukcars, s.window="periodic")
lastyear <- rep(decomp$time.series[110:113,"seasonal"],2)
fc <- fit$mean + lastyear
plot(ukcars,xlim=c(1980,2007))
```

but I get the error

```
lastyear <- rep(decomp$time.series[110:113,"seasonal"],2)
Error in `[.default`(decomp$time.series, 110:113, "seasonal") : 
subscript out of bounds
```

This was easy to find out why this is happening, the row index isn't numeric.

```
df = decomp$time.series
df
      seasonal    trend   remainder
1997 Q1  29.461732 409.5449  -2.7816187
1997 Q2  12.481745 418.2274  10.7778183
1997 Q3 -38.894178 427.0137 -18.5534968
1997 Q4  -3.049312 434.5440  19.2282932
```

I should be able to fix this taking the current row index and setting it to a new column in the df and resetting the rownames. But I am unable to do this. `rownames(df)` returns NULL and when doing `rownames(df) = 1:nrow(df)` I get

```
Error in `[.default`(df, 110:113, "seasonal") : subscript out of bounds
```

I also tried `ncol(df)` but that returns 3

EDIT: including `dput(df)`

```
dput(df)
structure(c(29.4617321114283, 12.481744937995, -38.8941781754736, 
-3.04931217790218, 29.4617321114283, 12.481744937995, -38.8941781754736, 
-3.04931217790218, 29.4617321114283, 12.481744937995, -38.8941781754736, 
-3.04931217790218, 29.4617321114283, 12.481744937995, -38.8941781754736, 
-3.04931217790218, 29.4617321114283, 12.481744937995, -38.8941781754736, 
-3.04931217790218, 29.4617321114283, 12.481744937995, -38.8941781754736, 
-3.04931217790218, 29.4617321114283, 12.481744937995, -38.8941781754736, 
-3.04931217790218, 29.4617321114283, 12.481744937995, -38.8941781754736, 
-3.04931217790218, 29.4617321114283, 409.544886542326, 418.227436805885, 
427.01367497542, 434.544018928925, 442.651085971855, 442.447639001895, 
437.267648318706, 432.966177328059, 431.539698434268, 439.341038640529, 
450.91900577231, 455.122749175224, 444.587943439341, 421.3536533291, 
395.452137518301, 375.326317915304, 367.770200274677, 369.335086887743, 
380.278749855951, 393.715056976157, 403.779846429226, 409.053577715943, 
404.884341815207, 404.446280975672, 407.109838578845, 412.446556196033, 
418.085913244093, 418.859041902176, 416.45346591907, 414.103454261138, 
409.700294883422, 405.663143500826, 401.068578490248, -2.78161865375392, 
10.7778182561204, -18.5534967999465, 19.2282932489768, -9.67081808328351, 
13.3026160601095, 5.26252985676808, -15.9688651501567, -0.505430545696072, 
-2.89078357852424, -4.23782759683684, 17.3345630026784, 20.2613244492306, 
-0.595398267095391, -21.4519593428274, 6.51799426259851, -10.1319323861056, 
-9.42183182573785, -5.59457168047692, 6.41425520174482, 16.5134214593455, 
-19.2833226539381, 25.8568363602669, -15.5069687977694, -12.2465706902731, 
8.35169886597168, 12.0212649313809, -7.06972972427383, -0.45719803049866, 
1.61680080086745, 8.24188329205163, -8.57183132292397, 2.26568939832384
), .Dim = c(33L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33"), c("seasonal", "trend", 
"remainder")), .Tsp = c(1997, 2005, 4), class = c("mts", "ts", 
"matrix"))
```

Comment: Can you post `dput(df)`?

Comment: Based on your provided `df`, I get no error if I run `rownames(df) = 1:nrow(df)`.

Comment: `ncol(df)` is 3 which should be.

Comment: I do not either, it just doesn't make changes to the df, or at least when you just print out the df. But when doing that then printing rowname(df) I get a list of strings with the numbers inside of them but still no change to the df when I print it out.

Comment: `rownames` for data frame should be characters. Why do you want to change them to numeric. Does `as.numeric(rownames(df))` help you?

Comment: The reason of subscript out of bounds is not "the row index isn't numeric". It's simply because you only have 33 rows. row names is not row index. Also `rownames` is for matrix like objects, `row.names` is for data frame.

Comment: If you want to reset the row numbering, then just do `rownames(df) <- NULL`